# How to write SQL with count and group by common fields from two tables

Tags: sql, join, count, group-by, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two tables in SQL Server 2008 R2:

```
Store:                      Record:
--------------              ------------------------
Shape       ID              PickedShape     Finished
Circle      1               Circle          Y
Circle      2               Circle          N
Circle      3               Square          N
Square      1               Square          N
Square      2               Oval            Y
Triangle    1               Oval            Y
```

I want to write a SQL query to output all the possible shapes and their counts across the two tables. I can write it in a silly way, like

```
select 
    'Circle', (select count(1) from Store where Shape = 'Circle'), 
    (select count(1) from Record where PickedShape = 'Circle'), 
    (select count(1) from Record where Finished = 'Y' and PickedShape = 'Circle') 
UNION
select 
    'Square', (select count(1) from Store where Shape = 'Square'), 
    (select count(1) from Record where PickedShape = 'Square'), 
    (select count(1) from Record where Finished = 'Y' and PickedShape = 'Square') 
UNION...
```

and go on, but that just silly and not efficient.

I think a more clever way is to use group by. Since some people may not like spoon feeding others, so here is what I tried

```
SELECT 
    Shape, COUNT(Shape) AS Available, Picked, Finished
FROM 
    Store 
FULL JOIN 
    (SELECT PickedShape, COUNT(1) As Picked, SUM(CASE WHEN Finished='Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Finished 
     FROM Record 
     GROUP BY PickedShape) t2 ON Store.Shape = t2.PickedShape
GROUP BY 
    Shape, Picked, Finished
```

and the output is

```
Shape   Available   Picked  Finished
NULL        0       2       2
Circle      3       2       1
Square      2       2       0
Triangle    1       NULL    NULL
```

You can see where the problems are.

First I want to have 'Oval' under Shape instead of NULL. Using FULL JOIN gives me all the variations in both the tables, but not showing them...

Second, I want Picked and Finished to show 0 instead of NULL for the missing ones.

Third, I want the SQL to be more efficient if possible.

How do you solve those problems?

Thank you!

Comment: You will probably have to do a union. Schema and values pls..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I a little bit modified your query
In first query you grouped by Shape, but 'Oval' not exists in first query. Hence Shape receive from derived query.Triangle not exists in derived query, hence its quantity equals 0.

```
SELECT 
  COALESCE(Shape, t2.PickedShape) AS Shape, COUNT(Shape) AS Available,
  ISNULL(Picked, 0) AS Picked, ISNULL(Finished, 0) AS Finished
FROM 
 Store 
FULL JOIN 
  (SELECT PickedShape, COUNT(1) As Picked, SUM(CASE WHEN Finished='Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Finished 
   FROM Record 
   GROUP BY PickedShape) t2 ON Store.Shape = t2.PickedShape
GROUP BY 
  Shape, t2.PickedShape, Picked, Finished
```

Comment: Hey excellent! Thank you! Now the only thing is, is there any more room to optimize the SQL.